# Why is there a line at the bottom of this combo box?

Tags: css, listview, combobox, javafx, javafx-8

I've tried everything to try and remove it, it doesn't look like it's a split pane or a separator either.

[image]

Added some padding to show it better:

[image]

All I have for code is a `ComboBox<String>` with elements added to it, no need to show that. As for css, I have this:

```
.combo-box {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: -1, -1, -1, -1;
}

.combo-box .list-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.combo-box-base .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.combo-box-base .arrow {
    -fx-shape: "M8.124,13.625l4.125-3.375v2.889l-4.125,3.86L4,13.139V10.25L8.124,13.625z";
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view {
    -fx-effect: null;
}
```

and

```
.combo-box {
    -fx-background-color: #2B545E;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view {
    -fx-background-color: #2B545E;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled {
    -fx-background-color: #2B545E;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #2E5A66;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #346673;
}
```

Using `Application.STYLESHEET_CASPIAN`.

Comment: Can you show some code? Your css, at least, and a cell factory, if you have one?

Comment: My guess is that `border-bottom` is set on that last element, but it's only a guess without code.

Comment: @divinecomedian `border-bottom` is not a valid css property in JavaFX.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought it was compiled CSS, but that was before code was posted.  Well whatever the JavaFX equivalent that gets compiled to CSS `border-bottom` is, I assume that's what is being set on the last element.  If you're using some kind of default/framework stylesheet, then it's probably set on there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is this style: `.combo-box-base .list-view .cell`

It can be easily seen that it's not just a line, but the non-filled content of the listview by specifying a larger height of the listview popup:

```
.combo-box-popup .list-view {
    -fx-pref-height:200;
}
```

Then your combobox will look like this:

[image]

So the solution is to colorize that area by adding this style:

```
.combo-box-base .list-view .cell  {
    -fx-background-color: #2B545E; 
}
```

And you'll get this:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! I'll give the bounty once the time is up

Answer (score 0):

Though late, I think this might help someone , especially those using `JFXCombobox`

```
.jfx-combo-box .input-line{
    -fx-pref-height: 0px;
}
.jfx-combo-box .input-focused-line{
    -fx-pref-height: 0px;
}
```